# Simple SQL based on column value

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a sql query to return rows based on specific conditions. Below are the tables :

```
Table L:
l_id
v_id
l_name

Table S:
g_id
s_id
e_id
l_id

Table G:
g_id
g_name
g_no
...
```

i did a left outer join to get values even if the S table is not set, so the select looks like :

```
select g_id, s_id, g_name, g_no, l_name
from g
left outer join s on s.g_id = g.g_id
left outer join l on l.l_id = s.l_id
```

and the result is :

```
g_id    s_id    g_name  g_no    l_name
3   s10 A   true    test
3   s9  A   true    test_7
17  {null}  B   false   test_8
```

In above result we get 2 rows because the s_id is assigned 2 times for different l_name.
I want to return the same table but I want to keep only the row with l_name = "test" when the column s_id <> {null}

I could do this in a post treatment, but the list will be really huge so, i prefer to find a solution with SQL.

Any idea is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to get only "test" when there are multiple rows?

Comment: Yes, only "test" for l_name when s_id is not null. In my example, it needs to return 1 line for g_id = 3 and l_name = "test" and 1 line for g_id = 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do it in the `where` clause:

```
select g_id, s_id, g_name, g_no, l_name
from g
left outer join s on s.g_id = g.g_id
left outer join l on l.l_id = s.l_id
where s_id is null or (s_id is not null and l_name = 'test')
```

Comment: Nice! I was thinking to something much more difficult :)